# Please help me understand this P2PKH transaction

Tags: p2pkh

I'm trying to understand Pay-to-Pubkey-Hash transactions. I picked a random P2PKH  transaction in a blockchain explorer: [ab3f542ad5add941f8ba4282cebab0cca81266a83cab6b98ebb8ae730477a570](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/ab3f542ad5add941f8ba4282cebab0cca81266a83cab6b98ebb8ae730477a570)

As far as I understand `0312437e326ef7bef6ea13209720f308548d2d205a4bf94e73bf8233ea7e6bb769` in the `scriptSig` is the public key and `3b10b087f293aecbb3af71e26d17f4e0ff4ea5f7` in the `scriptPubKey` is the `OP_HASH160` of the public key of the receiver. So I did the following:

1. SHA256(0312437e326ef7bef6ea13209720f308548d2d205a4bf94e73bf8233ea7e6bb769) = 7205ec1e595ce779b4d8b68fd909e00ef97eb0fdb8274951c7f923e2c82a898f
2. RIPEMD160(7205ec1e595ce779b4d8b68fd909e00ef97eb0fdb8274951c7f923e2c82a898f) = 73e440177e6b5e27eabef63905bb2e2c1616dc9d

I was expecting the second step to result in `3b10b087f293aecbb3af71e26d17f4e0ff4ea5f7`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the tool you're using to generate the hashes interprets the input as ASCII or UTF-8 characters, even though it should be interpreted as a hexadecimal number.

SHA256(0312437e326ef7bef6ea13209720f308548d2d205a4bf94e73bf8233ea7e6bb769) is actually e39ddbed20e2baba5b24f0ee4532249853d22b5d76c48a7a70ec2c373f895c01.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Now everything checks out.